# Xencenter Console is very slow

Tags: xenserver, xen

I am using xencenter to administer xenserver 6.2. Xencenter VM console is very slow. I am using vpn connection. I don't want to setup ports. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your XenCenter or reinstall it, if that doesn't work get onto a faster and more reliable network.